# Using (Submission and request) a database with a Android wearable

Tags: android, database, button, sql-update, wear-os

I want to write values into a database on a server when pressing a button on a **wearable app**. I tried the app on a ("normal") Android app (code below), and it just works fine. But as soon as I want to copy it to the wearable app nothing works. The only difference I made on the wearable app is in the Manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

Here is the app code which works on the handheld but doesn`t on the wear.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.demo.firstdatabaseapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
package de.demo.firstdatabaseapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button bSubmit;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        bSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);


        // This where the Values get entered inside the database
        bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            InputStream is = null;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Storing the values inside the editTexts inside the string variables
                String name = "Chuck";
                String age = "42";
                String email = "Norris@awesomeness.com";

                //Setting the nameValuePairs
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                //Adding the string variabls inside the nameValuePairs
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", age));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

                // Setting up the connection inside the try catch block

                try{
                    //Setting up the default http client
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    //Setting up the http post method and passing the url in case
                    // of online database and the ip address in case of localhost database.
                    //And the php file which serves as the link between the android app
                    // and the database

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://---.---.-.--:8888/tutorial.php");

                    //Passing the nameValuePairs inside the httpPost
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    //Getting the response
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    //Setting up the entity
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    //Setting up the content inside an input stream reader
                    is = entity.getContent();

                    //Displaying a toast if the data is entered successfully
                    String msg = "Data entered successfully";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                //Writing the catch blocks to handle the exceptions
                catch (ClientProtocolException e)
                {
                    Log.e("ClientProtocol", "Log_tag");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e("Log_tag", "IOException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });



    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my question in using the Teleport Library (github.com/Mariuxtheone/Teleport) so send data from the wear across the phone to a database.

My wear (Samsung Gear Live) doesn`t support a direct internet connection. In my case I need to send it first via Bluetooth to the handheld. That`s what cased the difference between using the code on the handheld and the wear.

For further information I found this talk on data syncing really interesting -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbbKCfCIyFA

Answer (score 0):

Most wearable devices currently do not support a direct Internet connection, so attempting to upload/download anything from a Wear app will not work.

You should use the [Data Layer API](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) to send the data to be saved to a companion app on the handheld device that can then do the uploading and let the Wear app know the result of what happened once the action has completed.

Comment: thank you for the hint! will check what possibilities I do have with Data Layer API.

Comment: I tried to operate the Data Layer API knowledge which is given in the developers training but I have absolutely no clue how to solve it. Could someone give me a cook book for my issue?